# Passing data from one controller to another in Dotnet Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am a newbie to the whole MVC pattern , stuck with the following issue:

I have 2 controllers, `PayReqController` and `PayResController`. I am trying to access data from one action of `PayReqController` to another action of `PayResController`. I have tried using `TempData`:

```
TempData["tsnpac"] = tsnpac;
```

But it doesn't work because we need to redirect to another controller after setting the `TempData`. Also tried using session `Session["TSNPAC"] = "TSNPAC";` to access it to another controller, but it is giving the value as `null`.

My scenario is that in `PayReqController`, inside an action I have a value which I need to get that in another controller without redirecting to that controller, because my use case is to redirect to some other URL which I get as a response from other service.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show your code but it sounds like you need to move code out of the controller.

Comment: Yes i am setting a value in first controller and moving into some xyz URL (Which i am getting it from a service as a response) then after redirecting to that URL and after passing some values there i am coming back to the 2nd controller. Code for which controller you want to see ? Is there a solution to get the values to another controller in my scenario or usecase ?

Answer (score 0):

To share data between the scope of a request (not just between controllers), you can use `HttpContext.Items`.

to share data:

```
//in the  first controller 

HttpContext.Items.Add("person", person);
```

And to use shared data:

```
//in the second controller

var person= HttpContext.Items["person"] as Person;
```

Comment: value of person is coming as null

Comment: Note that this approach is just for the scope of one request (not multiple request).

Comment: Ok , Is there any solution or approach for my scenario or use case , Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Session["TSNPAC"] = "TSNPAC";
> ```

As far as I know, we could share the session value between controller, about the session is null, perhaps the issue is related to the session expired time and the used of session in asp.net core.

To use session in asp.net Core, the Startup must contain:

- Any of the [IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache) memory caches. The IDistributedCache implementation is used as a backing store for session. For more information, see [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
- A call to **AddSession** in **ConfigureServices**.
- A call to **UseSession** in **Configure**.

The Startup.cs as below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // set the session expired time.
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

By using above configuration, we set the session expired time as 20 minutes.

Then, in the controller, we could use the following code to Get or Set the value in the session:

```
    public const string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        //Requires: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)))
        {
            //set value to session
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor"); 
        }
        //Get value from session
        var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);

        //used to display value in the view page.
        ViewData["name"] = name; 
        return View();
    }
```

If you want to use session to store object, you have to add the SessionExtensions, check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

More detail information about using session, check [Session State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state).

If still can't get the value using session, you can consider store the value in the cache or database.

Comment: This was the steps i followed to set session and access it to another controller after redirection but the value i get is null , Is it valid in my scenario , Can i access the session value from one controller to another in Dotnet Core 3.1 MVC in spite of redirecting to the URL received as the response from a web service and coming back to the 2 nd controller to access the value.

Comment: Is there anything specific i need to try to not get the value null or some other approach , please suggest

Comment: Hi @TSNandakumar, Based on your description, I also created an Asp.net core 3.1 MVC application, the session could be shared between controllers (create a new asp.net core mvc application and use above code to configure the session). After checking the [Session state](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0),it seems that the session also related to the cookie, please check the browser and make sure it enable cookies. Besides, when using `AddSession`, make the session cookie Essential:`services.AddSession(op => {op.Cookie.IsEssential = true;});`.

Comment: Hi @Zhi Lv, Could you please refer to my below post what i exactly tried using the session

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps :
In startup.cs ,In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method `

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();services.AddSession(options =>
{options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;});
```

`In Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) ,`app.UseSession();`In 1st Controller`string merchantCode = "T S Nandakumar"; HttpContext.Session.SetString("Code", merchantCode);`In 2nd Controller`string codetest = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Code");`

But in the 2nd controller after the redirect of the URL, Getting Null value , Could you please let me know whether am i missing any steps here as per yours?

Answer (score 0):

I tried TempData but different than this approach and it worked.

I serialized my list when storing it in TempData

AccountController:

```
TempData["BiUsers"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
```

(users is an IEnumerable of UserModel)

And deserialized it in another controller in which I wanted to use that IEnumerable.

HomeController:

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<UserModel>>(TempData["BiUsers"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using object data type from one controller to another.

HomeController

```
public HomeController: Controller{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    public IActionResult Index(){
         TempData["var1"] = obj;
         return Content("");
    }
}
```

---

AboutController

```
public AboutController: Controller{
    public IActionResult Index(){
        MyObject obj1 = TempData["var1"] as MyObject
    }
}
```

---